# self.request.form not iterable?

Tags: python, forms, werkzeug

Hello I am making a form in HTML and python and I am having a problem with processing the arguments

the problem comes in this section

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="brands" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="brands" value="2" />
</form>
```

and in the python I am using a self.request.form object to retrieve the arguments
the problem is if I do something like

```
for b in brands:
   print b
```

it will just print out 1 even if both of them are in the self.request.form object

USING Werkzeug Framework

ANSWERED:
I found you can retrieve a list of the same named inputs using this syntax

```
self.request.form.getlist('brands')
```

Comment: You may want to say which framework. Just sayin'

Comment: sorry I am like the UI person stuff like this doesnt normally cross my path. The framework is werkzeug

Comment: Great, thanks. I just added the Werkzeug tag

Comment: You should put that `ANSWERED` section in an answer then mark that as a solution.

Comment: Cant for another 6 hours or something because I dont have enough rep if someone else wants to post it I will mark it

Comment: Well, personally, I would like to give you a +1 for it, so if you put it as an answer (and respond here), I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you can retrieve a list of the same named inputs using this syntax

```
self.request.form.getlist('brands')
```